# Flutter: Getting more than 200Hz from sensor_plus on Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sensors

I am developing an application where I need to retrieve IMU data as fast as possible, thus I would like to set the sampling frequency to more than 200Hz.

Things I have already done:

- Setting the sampling period to 0 in the sensor_plus function:

```
_streamSubscriptions.add(userAccelerometerEventStream(samplingPeriod: Duration(milliseconds:0)).listen((UserAccelerometerEvent event) { ...}
```

- Including `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HIGH_SAMPLING_RATE_SENSORS"/>` in the manifest file of my app and also in the manifest file of the sensor_plus package
- Modifying the code of the sensor_plus package to use

```
sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
```

Any help would be appreciated :)